# setTimeout only runs once (using function ref)

Tags: javascript

Here is a codepen: [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMrxwM)

The problem is that setTimeout is only running once:

```
var inter = document.getElementById("interval");
var i = 1;

window.setTimeout(function () {
    i++;
    inter.innerHTML = "Interval: " + i;
}, 500)
```

I've checked a other questions on SO and people are calling their function rather than passing a function reference:

```
window.setTimeout(myFunc(), 1000);
```

But I'm passing a function ref so I must be doing something else wrong. Can someone please help me find out what it is?

Edit: Thanks! I can't believe I mixed those two up!

Comment: `window.setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);` , you are setting the first argument as the returned value of function , instead set the function reference.

Comment: You should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want this function to run every 1000 ms.

Comment: I think you want setInterval() rather than setTimeout()

Comment: Too bad you deleted your today's palindrome question. I was about to post an answer. Can you consider restoring it?

Comment: I was really interested in seeing what other people could come up with! Unfortunately I kept getting downvoted ... but I don't have a SO reputation to protect so I'll repost it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is meant to run only once.

Use `setInterval` instead.

```
var inter = document.getElementById("interval");
var i = 1;

window.setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    inter.innerHTML = "Interval: " + i;
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same thing over and over use `setInterval`

```
var inter = document.getElementById("interval");
var i = 1;

window.setInterval(function () {
  i++;
  inter.innerHTML = "Interval: " + i;
}, 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `setTimeout()`, e.g. from 1 to 100,  you can do it like this:

```
var inter = document.getElementById("interval");
var i = 1;

function run() {
    inter.innerHTML = i;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if(i < 101) { // Or without the if-statement to run it infinite
            run();
        }
        i += 1;
    }, 50);
}

run();
```